# What does "…not immune to such charges" mean?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, gre

This is a GRE text completion sentence

> To claim that the prevailing account of an important incident, whether it happened last century or last week, is corrupted by disinformation is to enter _______ waters, for any subsequent account offered is similarly _______ such charges.

These were the options for each blank, the emboldened ones being the right choices.

familiar
uncharted
**treacherous**

related to
guilty of
**not immune to**

What is the sentence talking about when they say "for any subsequent account offered is similarly not immune to such charges." What charges? Because I don't quite understand the second part of the sentence I have a hard time picking a choice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim that the account in question is corrupted by disinformation, is the charge.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather awkwardly stated question, but "not immune to" simply means that any other claim could also be subject to disinformation.  MY condolence to people taking aptitude test.

Comment: I know right. :( It's for grad school.